# Пропало место после установки Kryptex

Tags: майнинг

Я сначала установил `kryptex`, он мне установил какие-то компоненты то-ли для `cpu` то-ли для `gpu` и у меня пропало около 15 гб на диске. После удаления самого kryptex'а это место не освободилось. Где могут лежать файлы, которые не удалились? Я скачал 100% не вирус, т.к качал с оф. сайта

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Меня зовут Дмитрий, я один из агентов Поддержки Криптекса.

При установке Криптекс просто скачивает майнеры. Криптекс автоматически увеличивает файл подкачки, который хранится на диске С. Файла подкачки может попросту не хватить, чтобы майнеры работали корректно. Удалите или уменьшите файл подкачки и место вновь "вернется".

Answer (score 0):

Kryptex возможно докачал блокчейны. Скачай и глянь через эту программу https://wiztreefree.com/ где лежит самый большой файл с названием XMR ETH ZCH и т.п. А для майнинга на GPU используй Phoenixminer ; T-rex . А для CPU XMRIG